# Using multiple xsl templates with one xml

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, xslt

I'm new to xsl templates, but I haven't found a way yet to do what I'm wanting. It seems like this should be possible.

What I want is to have multiple templates for one xml file. I'm doing an online resume, so I have my resume.xml file. I would like to have my onlineResume.xsl template, my downloadWord.xsl template, and my downloadPDF.xsl template. These three templates would be rendered based on what tab is selected on a master webpage.

Right now I have the below as test. The bodies aren't fleshed out, obviously, but I can't get past linking more than one stylesheet depending on which link is followed. I'm open to php, javascript/jquery, xsl, xml, xpath or whatever is needed. My website is developed server-side with php.

HTML home page

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="./resume.xml">Online Resume</a>
<a href="./resume.xml">Download Word</a>
<a href="./resume.xml">Download PDF</a>
</body>
</html>
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="onlineCV.xsl"?>
<resume>
    <personal_info>
        <birthdate>07/08/1988</birthdate>
    </personal_info>
    <jobs>
        <job>
            <company>Radio Shack</company>
            <title>Sales Representative</title>
            <startdate>01/01/2011</startdate>
            <enddate>02/02/2011</enddate>
            <duration>1.5yrs</duration>
            <sortdate>20110101</sortdate>
        </job>
        <job>
            <company>Radio Shack2</company>
            <title>Sales Representative</title>
            <startdate>01/01/2013</startdate>
            <enddate>02/02/2013</enddate>
            <duration>1.5yrs</duration>
            <sortdate>20130202</sortdate>
        </job>
    </jobs>
</resume>
```

Online Resume

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Resume</h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="resume/jobs/job">
        <xsl:sort select="sortdate" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <div>

            <xsl:value-of select="company" /> - <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Download Word

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My Word Download</h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="resume/jobs/job">
        <xsl:sort select="sortdate" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <div>

            <xsl:value-of select="company" /> - <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Download PDF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My PDF Download</h2>
        <xsl:for-each select="resume/jobs/job">
        <xsl:sort select="sortdate" data-type="number" order="descending" />
        <div>

            <xsl:value-of select="company" /> - <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use different XSLT templates to generate different outputs from an XML. But you do not generate different outputs, you send one output to the browser and it transforms it.

Think about it. At the moment here is no value/indicator that decides which template should be used.

You have two possibilities:

### Server Side Processing using XSLTProcessor (PHP)

```
$xsltFile = 'onlineCV.xsl';

$xmlDom = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDom->loadXml($xml);
$xslDom = new DOMDocument();
$xslDOM->load($xsltFile);
$processor = new XsltProcessor();
$processor->importStylesheet($xslDom);

echo $processor->transformToXml($xmlDom);
```

This will generate and output depending on the XSLT and output it.

### Client Side Processing (Browser)

Generate different XML outputs, that reference different XSLT templates and send them to the Browser

```
$xsltFile = 'onlineCV.xsl';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$dom->insertBefore(
  $dom->createProcessingInstruction(
    'xml-stylesheet', 
    'type="text/xsl" href="'.$xsltFile.'"'
  ),
  $dom->documentElement
);

echo $dom->saveXml();
```

Demo: https://eval.in/162137

Comment: As far as best practice, would one of these methods work best or using an include for the xml work best (outlined in link). I did some digging and found a possibility late last night. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196139/xml-entity-include-not-displaying/24196476?noredirect=1#comment37355451_24196476

Comment: Browsers seem not to resolve external entities, so using a wrapper XML with the template and including the main XML as an entity will not work.

Comment: Yeah, I just tested that one and the template won't recognize the elements in the entity. Suppose I'll use PHP. Thanks for the help.