# XML entity include not displaying

Tags: xml, validation, entity, dtd

I am attempting to include an entity within my xml, however, it doesn't seem to be displaying. I'm very new to XML, so if what I've found in my research isn't best practice, I'm more than open to changing.

XML to Include

```
<resume>
    <personal_info>
        <birthdate>07/08/1988</birthdate>
    </personal_info>
    <jobs>
        <job>
            <company>Radio Shack</company>
            <title>Sales Representative</title>
            <startdate>01/01/2011</startdate>
            <enddate>02/02/2011</enddate>
            <duration>1.5yrs</duration>
            <sortdate>20110101</sortdate>
        </job>
        <job>
            <company>Radio Shack2</company>
            <title>Sales Representative</title>
            <startdate>01/01/2013</startdate>
            <enddate>02/02/2013</enddate>
            <duration>1.5yrs</duration>
            <sortdate>20130202</sortdate>
        </job>
    </jobs>
</resume>
```

XML for inclusion

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE downloadWord SYSTEM "resume.dtd"[
<!ENTITY resume SYSTEM "resume.xml">
]>
<thing>
&resume;
</thing>
```

DTD

```
<!ELEMENT thing (resume)>
<!ELEMENT resume (personalinfo, jobs)>
<!ELEMENT personalinfo (birthdate)>
<!ELEMENT birthdate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT jobs (company,title,startdate,enddate,duration,sortdate)>
<!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT startdate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT enddate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT duration (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT sortdate (#PCDATA)>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word that comes after `DOCTYPE` must be the *document root element* (replace `downloadWord` with `thing`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE thing SYSTEM "resume.dtd"[
    <!ENTITY resume SYSTEM "resume.xml">
]>
<thing>
    &resume;
</thing>
```

That should include the file (which will cause validation errors, since the document doesn't match the DTD. To fix the DTD so it matches the instance (you might want to do the opposite):

*Line 2*: Change `personalinfo` in to `personal_info`:

```
<!ELEMENT resume (personal_info, jobs)>
```

*Line 5*: Replace `jobs` with `job`:

```xml
<!ELEMENT job (company,title,startdate,enddate,duration,sortdate)>
```

Add this *new line*:

```
<!ELEMENT jobs (job+)>
```

This is the final `resume.dtd` DTD which validates the file above:

```
<!ELEMENT thing (resume)>
<!ELEMENT resume (personal_info, jobs)>
<!ELEMENT personal_info (birthdate)>
<!ELEMENT birthdate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT jobs (job+)>
<!ELEMENT job (company,title,startdate,enddate,duration,sortdate)>
<!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT startdate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT enddate (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT duration (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT sortdate (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: I setup your environment here, with all the files in the same directory, and it worked. With the corrections above it even validates. Check your environment.